# Error downloading

Tags: qt, download, policy, qwebview

to download a console returns the following error:

> Frame load interrupted by policy change

**Example:**

```
<a href="app.exe">Start Download</a>
```

**Console Preview:**
[image]

Should I configure something in the **Compiler** or **QWebSettings**?

Comment: Maybe the "exe" extension is the source of this allergy. Executables are generally blocked from direct download to avoid malicious code. This may explain the word "policy".

Comment: The download works (I use unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply*) and setForwardUnsupportedContent(true)), the problem really is the strange message. I wonder what it is that message/error. Could you tell me what why it appears? When I download should appear canceled and not failed (as occurs in normal browsers). Will I have to "edit/rewrite" function `unsupportedContent` using `QWebView->setPage(new myClassPageRewrite())` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered.
In conventional Webkit browsers, the place to download the console shows how the request canceled, so before turning to "download manager" of the browser the request should be canceled.

**solution:**

```
//replace [QWebView] by your WebView
connect([QWebView]->page(), SIGNAL(unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply*)),
this, SLOT(downloadContent(QNetworkReply*)));

...

void [main class]::downloadContent(QNetworkReply *reply){
    //Replace "[main class]" by "Class" having the signs used in WebView.

    [QWebView]->stop();
    //solution: stop loading --replace [QWebView] by your WebView

    /*function to donwload*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: hard to tell without a proper backtrace I requested in the comments, but it looks like the warning might actually be harmless.

**Original**:
That's because the `QWebView` [doesn't know](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35656) what to do with your `app.exe` file -- it's not an HTML page or a `text/plain` document or a supported image, after all. The `QWebView` class is not a web browser; you apparently want to start a download of some file, but there's no full-blown download manager in that class. You will have to provide your own code for this -- the code will have to ask for a proper location to save it, etc.

You can start with [`QWebPage::setLinkDelegationPolicy`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#linkDelegationPolicy-prop) and handle this particular click yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my code is downloading normally.
I have not used `QWebPage::setLinkDelegationPolicy`.

I used `connect(QWebPage, SIGNAL(unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(signalDownload(QNetworkReply*)));` and `setForwardUnsupportedContent(true)`, the download works perfectly with it.

The only problem is the message of `policy` which is strange (I do not understand why this policy or what it is). If you can edit your answer I would be grateful. Good day.

Comment: I can set `setLinkDelegationPolicy` only for `mimetypes`  unrecognized? And mimetypes recognized continue to function normally (standard mode)?

Comment: Okay, I've checked the qtwebkit source and it looks like the warning gets printed even in rather harmless cases. It would be interesting to see a backtrace from this error -- ``WebCore::MainResourceLoader::stopLoadingForPolicyChange()`` appears to be the function to set your breakpoint in. How does the stack trace look like?